# Youtube Api in node js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, google-api, youtube-data-api

I am creating an application in react-native/node/express/mongodb. I have a functionality where the admin will be able to upload videos and will allow specific kinds of users to watch specific videos on specific dates.

So for that, I thought I should upload videos on YouTube, make them private, and then display them to specific users within my mobile application (react native). For that, I don't want the users to log in with Google or authenticate their Google accounts, etc.

Is there any way to allow my application to fetch the videos from YouTube?

Comment: its use case is out side the abilities of the YouTube api.